# Why does $(\log n)^{\log n} = \Omega(n^{10})$?

Tags: logarithms

Why does $(\log n)^{\log n} = \Omega(n^{10})$?

In other words, show that $(\log n)^{\log n} \ge c\cdot n^{10})$ for some constant $c>0$.

I'm not sure how to prove it, how can I write $(\log n)^{\log n}$ in a simpler way?

Comment: Are we using Big Omega notation?  And if so, which?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation

Comment: @SimpleArt I've edited the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(\log(n))^{\log(n)}\leq Cn^{10}$? The inequality you've written is clearly false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** take logarithm of both sides

Comment: Thank you, I did and got to: $lognlog(logn) \gt 10logn$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS $\log \log n > 10$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Yes, then divide both side by $\log n$ for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$(\log n)^{\log n}=\exp(\log n\cdot \log(\log(n)))=n^{\log(\log(n))}$$
Hence $(\log n)^{\log n} = \Omega(n^{a})$ for any $a>0$ because $\log(\log(n))$ goes to infinity and it is therefore bigger than any constant.